# Simulate text input on mac using python

Tags: python, macos, text, terminal, keyboard

I have an opened word document and I have already build something to automatically click and to open it. Now, I would like to write a python program that when executed will type "Hello" into the document. How can I do this?

Comment: Probably much easier to write a text document in Python and get Word to open that...

Comment: I agree-- the final product is trying to automatically draw a picture (including text) in paintbrush, but I wanted to make it work in word first.

Comment: could probably do this with something like [sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [PyAutoGUI](http://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheatsheet.html#keyboard-functions)?

```
import pyautogui
pyautogui.typewrite('Hello world!\n', interval=secs_between_keys)  # useful for entering text, newline is Enter
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyUserInput/ and through importing

from pymouse import PyMouse
from pykeyboard import PyKeyboard